# Can Poetry scan the project path and list dependencies?

Tags: python-poetry

I want to migrate one project already done to Poetry but couldn't find the equivalent to "pipreqs /path/to/project/"

So i have to run pipreqs then "poetry add" manually

Comment: As far as I know: no, Poetry can not "scan the project path and list dependencies".

Answer (score -1):

I use pireqs and then ask chatgpt to transform it into pyproject.toml format. It's not the prettiest way, but it works.